# Has anyone run into problems in TortoiseSVN where the 'author' isn't written to the log?

Tags: tortoisesvn, svn

I have someone connecting to my repository using the url (substituted the IP address):
**svn+ssh://craig@123.45.67.89/subversion**

Yet when they commit files, the author entry is "null".

According to this article: http://tortoisesvn.net/node/80
it should be working fine.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your server configuration in `[repository]/conf/svnserve.conf` file if it has set

```
anon-acces=write
auth-access=write
```

Usually, with the default settings

```
anon-access = read
auth-access = write
```

(you can just comment out the lines), the author information should be preserved.